# How to modify "stream_autocomplete" from Outlook?

Tags: outlook, autocomplete

I've been trying to modify the `Stream_Autocomplete` cache file in Outlook (deleting all autocomplete with a certain domain), but I can't figure out how `:/`...

1. First my plan was to get the cache file from `RoamCache` folder, decode it, rewrite it without the users I don't want, and then save it where it was before (while making sure that during the process Outlook is closed so that it doesn't overwrite it when closed). But I don't understand the encoding used.. I found that documentation in link with that but I don't really understand it:
   [Autocomplete Stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/autocomplete-stream).
2. I've tried using MAPI but that didn't lead to anything because that data is not accessible from MAPI.
3. Then I tried using IMAP but couldn't figure out how to connect to the host (it's a private domain).

At this point I'm just back at trying to figure out a way for my first idea.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to stackoverflow!  However, please don’t spam tags; your question currently has no relevant to python or imap.

Comment: Sorry, I guess you did mention IMAP.  This is certainly not exposed via IMAP; IMAP is a mail retrieval protocol only.

Comment: @Max Oh okay sorry it's my first time asking questions here, i didnt really know what to tag °°`, thanks for your answer i'll forget about doing it with IMAP then 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using Redemption (any language, I am its author) is an option, it exposes nicknames through the [RDONicknames](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdonicknames.htm) object and allows to read and modify nicknames on either session, Exchange mailbox, or NK2 file level.

Comment: Thank you i'll take a look into that

Comment: (i'm not sure about what i'm going to say but..) 
Is REdemption a library that has to be installed ?
(because i have to be able to access and modify the autocomplete stream on a lot of clients and can only use a simple script that will be distributed)

Comment: Yes, Redemption is a library which can be deployed with your application.

Comment: Hello i am comming back to you because i have been trying to create a python for that project but i'm getting a lot of problems, then i went back to see the post i had made on stack overflow and ended up seeing your coment again. I think it's the best solution, could you please help me understand how i could use redemption with python ? (to decode all the binary file with all the different property types in there is just so long)

Comment: Do you mean you have a standalone N2K file? Or that you are opening nicknames from some Outlook store?

Comment: That i am opening the nicknames (autocomplete stream) from some outlook store (but if the file is needed i know where to find the Stream_Autocomplete.dat)

Comment: Redemption is a regular COM object (much like `Outlook.Application`), and you can easily use it in Python (`win32com.client.Dispatch("Redemption.RDOSession")` etc.). It should be pretty easy to convert any of the samples scripts at the url above to Python.

Comment: Thank you ! I noticed you need admin rights to use Redemption, would there be a way to put it next to the code and still be able to use it ? (i dont know if i'm clear but what i mean is if there is a way to use it without admin rights on a machine ?)

Comment: Redemption does not require admin right to install (install.exe that comes with it is a just a quick way to install it, and it tries to copy the dlls to Program Files, hence the admin rights). Copy the dlls to any folder and install them using regsvr32.exe - it will be happy to install itself in HKCU if installing in HKLM is not possible.

Comment: Thank you for your time and patience ! This works great  I’ll test it on an other machine and come back to you to tell you how it went 

Comment: hello, if i understood well you are the developper of this library right ? so i wanted to make sure i understood well, if i buy the distributable version, i will be able to sell the software i made that uses your library as long as the price of it does not exceed the price paid for the license ?

Comment: Yes, I am. It has nothing to do with price - the condition is that Redemption must be an integral part of your app, so you don't just repackage Redemption. There is also limitation on freeware apps.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Nickname cache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff625288.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article in MSDN which describes all possible ways for editing nickname caches.

For Outlook 2007, the autocomplete stream is stored in a file with the same name as the profile and an extension of .nk2. For example, if the default profile of "outlook" is used, the file will be called "outlook.nk2". The .nk2 file is stored in the `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Outlook` folder.

**Outlook 2010 and later**

Outlook 2010 or Outlook 2013 reads the autocomplete stream from a message in the Associated Contents table of the Inbox of the mail account’s delivery store. This hidden message has a message class and subject of `IPM.Configuration.Autocomplete`. The autocomplete stream is stored on this message in the `PR_ROAMING_BINARYSTREAM` property (`PidTagRoamingBinary` Canonical Property). The autocomplete data may be temporarily cached in an autocomplete .dat file located in `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\RoamCache`. However, the .dat file is only a cache and is not used to write back to the delivery store when the user exits Outlook 2010 and later.

On the page mentioned you can also find recommendation for editing the cache programmatically:

- Never partially modify the autocomplete stream. The supported interaction is to 1) read the entire autocomplete stream into memory, 2) modify the memory structure, and 3) write the entire stream back to either the Associated  -Contents table of the Inbox of the mail account’s delivery store (for Outlook 2010 or Outlook 2013) or to the local .nk2 file (Outlook 2007).
- Do not interact with the autocomplete stream while Outlook is running. If Outlook is running while you modify the stream, it will likely overwrite your changes when it shuts down.
- Do not write properties of type `PT_MV_UNICODE` and `PR_MV_STRING8` into an autocomplete stream to be consumed by Microsoft Outlook 2003. These properties are only understood by Outlook 2007, Outlook 2010, and Outlook 2013.
- When developing code that interacts with Outlook 2007, we recommend that you lock the .nk2 file from modification by other processes while you are reading and writing it using standard file locking APIs (for example, LockFile in C/C++ and FileStream.Lock in C#).
- Only modify the properties of types that are from the row-set of the autocomplete stream. For more information about the autocomplete stream properties and property types, see Autocomplete Stream.

The .nk2 file format is described in depth in the [Outlook 2003/2007 NK2 File Format and Developer Guidelines](http://portalvhds6gyn3khqwmgzd.blob.core.windows.net/files/NK2/NK2WithBinaryExample.pdf) document. Also you may find the [Understanding Outlook's Auto-Complete Cache (*.NK2)](http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/email/understanding-outlooks-autocomplete-cache-nk2/) article helpful.

As you can see dealing with autocomplete cache in Outlook is not an easy task which requires a low-level code (Extended MAPI). That's why I'd suggest to consider using Redemption as Dmitry suggested.

Comment: Thank you i really understand better how it works. Would you happen to have any pointers on how to retrieve this Associated Contents Table with MAPI ?

Comment: The [Folder.GetStorage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.folder.getstorage) method obtains a `StorageItem` on a `Folder` object using the identifier specified by `StorageIdentifier` and has the identifier type specified by `StorageIdentifierType`. The `StorageItem` is a hidden item in the `Folder`, which roams with the account and is available online and offline.

Comment: `hidden_class = account.Folders['inbox'].GetStorage("IPM.Configuration", 2)
print(hidden_class)` I Tried that out but i get a different object each time... (would you have an example of how to read that hidden message located at IPM.Configuration.Autocomplete ?)

Comment: Try to use MFCMAPI for exploring internals.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and your time ! i'm Sorry if i'm being slow at understanding, it's my first time using MAPI. 
I Found the Associated Content found at IPM.Configuration.Autocomplete and now i'm just having a hard time using the [PropertyAccessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/vba/api/outlook.propertyaccessor).[GetProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperty?view=net-6.0#system-type-getproperty(system-string)) function.. when i pass in the string argument "PR_ROAMING_BINARYSTREAM" it tells me that it's an incorect parameter...

Comment: Never mind i got the binary stream haha °°` now i just need to find a way to understand it modify it and rewrite it